# Get JSON data from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, nsdictionary

I have struct in my api

```
{
    "Hall":"Hall",
    "Date":20180501,
    "Prices":[
        {
            "Time":1,
            "Price":4000
        },
        {
            "Time":2,
            "Price":4000
        },
        {
            "Time":3,
            "Price":4000
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I'm stuck and can't pull out the price and time. I understand that there were many question, but I still can't understand, please help.

I use this code:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://<...>/api/prices?hall=<...>&date=20180501")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.httpMethod = "GET" 

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        } else {

            do {

                if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                    // ... 

                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }

            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I'm new with json, and just started learning it. I know it's easy, but I can't figure it out. I also know that i can use codable and decodable, but now I need to get price and time in this implementation.

Comment: Do not use `NSDictionary / NSArray` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system. Use native types (`[String:Any]`, `[Any]` / `[[String:Any]]`).

Comment: and what should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Product Structure:**

```
struct Product{
    
    let time:Int
    let price:Int
    
    init(_ object:[String:Int]){
        
        self.time = object["Time"] ?? 0
        self.price = object["Price"] ?? 0
    }
}
```

**Class Variable:**

```
var products = [Product]()
```

**JSON parsing:**

```
do{
    
    if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
        
        //Use Swift dictionary instead of NSDictionary

        if let prices = jsonObject["Prices"] as? [[String:Int]]{
            
            for price in prices{
                
                self.products.append(Product(price))
            }
        }
    }
    
}catch{
    print("Error: ",error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Now, your `products` `Array` will contain all `Price` and `Time`

**Example:**

```
for product in products{
    
    print("Time:",product.time)
    print("Price:",product.price)
}
```

**Output:**

> Time: 1
>
> Price: 4000
>
> Time: 2
>
> Price: 4000
>
> Time: 3
>
> Price: 4000

**Note:** For better understanding, this is my [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxT1bKZ1HyQ&list=PLT7YNwQNKSPDgymAvqhbphhYxJHWeYsX6) series about JSON parsing in swift 4

Answer (score 5):

First of all **don't use `NSArray / NSDictionary`**, use native Swift types.

The value for key `Prices` is an array of `[String:Int]` dictionaries:

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any], 
   let prices = jsonResult["Prices"] as? [[String:Int]] {
    for price in prices {
        print(price["Time"]!, price["Price"]!)
    }
}
```

---

However I would recommended to decode the JSON into a struct which is very simple in Swift 4

```
struct Item : Decodable {
    let hall : String
    let date : Int
    let prices : [Price]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case hall = "Hall",  date = "Date", prices = "Prices"}
}

struct Price  : Decodable {
    let time, price : Int

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case time = "Time",  price = "Price"}
}
```

---

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data!)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var timeArray = [String]()
    var priceArray = [String]()
    if  jsonResult.object(forKey:"Prices") as? NSArray != nil
    {
        let pricesArray = jsonResult.object(forKey:"Prices") as! NSArray
        for i in 0..<self.pricesArray.count
        {
            // Getting Time
            if jsonResult.object(forKey:"Time") as? Int != nil
            {
                self.timeArray.append(jsonResult.object(forKey:"Time") as! Int)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Time is not a intrger")
            }
            // Getting Price
            if jsonResult.object(forKey:"Price") as? Int != nil
            {
                self.priceArray.append(jsonResult.object(forKey:"Price") as! Int)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Price is not a intrger")
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Empty Array")
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any], let pirces = json["prices"] // checking json is formed well.
{
 for price in prices { // iterating throught array that you received. 
    print (price["Price"])
  }
}
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).